# Facebook Workplace: Conversation API bug "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable"

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-workplace

When I tried to fetch messages in workplace using conversation API Query ([https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{id}/conversations?fields=id,updated_time,messages.limit(1000){id,created_time,from.fields(id,name,email),to,message,attachments,shares}&limit=30&access_token=access-token](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/%7Bid%7D/conversations?fields=id,updated_time,messages.limit(1000)%7Bid,created_time,from.fields(id,name,email),to,message,attachments,shares%7D&limit=30&access_token=access-token))

I got following response:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": true,
    "code": 2,
    "fbtrace_id": "Ac0VVk58Ysk058266TMeTiK"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just found by hit and trial by removing **

> shares

** field from API query and it works. This field is giving me such error.